# How can I escape this string?

Tags: c#, string, escaping, c#-interactive

How can I escape `Expression\("(?!").*", [0-9]+\)>`?

I tried `Expression\\(\"(?!\").*\", [0-9]+\\)>` but running

```
Print("Expression\\(\"(?!\").*\", [0-9]+\\)>");
```

on VS C# Interactive, it prints:

```
"Expression\\(\"(?!\").*\", [0-9]+\\)>"
```

With the backlashes duplicated.

Comment: What do you mean by "returns"? The debugger will display escaped strings. Try printing it to the console.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` cracks it. Maybe it's some behaviour of the C# Interactive `Print(String)` method.

Comment: @vnbrs Yes, the C# interactive Print(string) method prints the string escaped, as it would appear between quotation marks as a string literal in a C# source file. I saw somebody mention that in a comment just recently.

Comment: Agreed.  I also just tested it.  I'm not sure why it is being interpreted differently though.

Comment: `Print(string)` prints the quotations marks of the string. Perhaps it's behaving as expected.

Comment: Run in zigzag pattern. It's hard for them to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# Interactive `Print(String)` method prints the string as it is, without evaluating the espace characters.

Use the `Console.WriteLine(String)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
        string s = @"Expression\(""(?!"").*"", [0-9]+\)>";

        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

This works.